# Remove the name of the recipient from Gmail’s autocomplete

Tags: gmail, automation

When Gmail autocompletes a recepient's email it goes something like: `"John Stewart" <john@stewart.net>,`.

Can I force Gmail to remove the name (John Stewart) and leave only the email? And manually deleting the name is not a solution here, because it's manual and error-prone.

For example: `<john@stewart.net>,`

If possible I would like Gmail to be able to find the email based on the name. So searching should utilize the name, but the recepient shouldn't see how I named him.

Answer (score 1):

The only way of doing this would be to "Name" your contact with the email address.

For example, in the example you have provided, your Contact would look like:

Name: john@stewart.net
Email: john@stewart.net

(I tried it just now and this method seems to work for me)

Comment: Yeah, I know that works, but then if in my contacts I have John Stewart as "Z John Stewart I know him from Silvia, he's a mechanic", then sending an email to him, will reveal all that extra info.

Comment: And, yes, I know there are extra fields for that, but I sync an iPhone with a google account, so either those fields are lost, or search functionality doesn't work on them.

Comment: @mist, are you saying the "sync an iPhone" can't handle syncing the "Notes" field of a google contact?

Comment: It can, but I want the name to have the extra info, otherwise I will be lost in my contacts.